# Zooming in/out while using ginput function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinates, zooming, ginput

I am using the `ginput` function in MATLAB to use the cursor to collect many x,y coordinates on images. I am following a certain path along the image and need to zoom-in to get a precise coordinates, but the zoom-in option is disabled while using `ginput`. Any ideas of how to get around this issue?

Here is the very simple code I am using.

```
A = imread('image1.tif');
B = imshow(A);
[x,y] = ginput; 
% at this point i scan the image and click many times, and
% ideally i would like to be able to zoom in and out of the image to better 
% aim the cursor and obtain precise xy coordinates
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the way to do it is to take advantage of the "button" output of the `ginput` function, i.e.,

`[x,y,b]=ginput;`

`b` returns the mouse button *or keyboard key* that was pressed. Choose your two favorite keys (e.g. [ and ], characters 91 and 93) and write some zoom in/zoom out code to handle what happens when those keys are pressed:

```
A = imread('image1.png');
B = imshow(A);
X = []; Y = [];
while 0<1
    [x,y,b] = ginput(1); 
    if isempty(b); 
        break;
    elseif b==91;
        ax = axis; width=ax(2)-ax(1); height=ax(4)-ax(3);
        axis([x-width/2 x+width/2 y-height/2 y+height/2]);
        zoom(1/2);
    elseif b==93;
        ax = axis; width=ax(2)-ax(1); height=ax(4)-ax(3);
        axis([x-width/2 x+width/2 y-height/2 y+height/2]);
        zoom(2);    
    else
        X=[X;x];
        Y=[Y;y];
    end;
end
[X Y]
```

The `(1)` in `ginput(1)` is important so that you're only getting one click/keypress at a time.

The enter key is the default `ginput` break key, which returns an empty `b`, and is handled by the first `if` statement.

If key 91 or 93 was pressed, we zoom out (`zoom(1/2)`) or zoom in (`zoom(2)`), respectively. The couple lines using `axis` center the plot on your cursor, and are important so you can zoom on particular parts of the image.

Else, add the cursor coordinates `x,y` to your set of coordinates `X,Y`.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative method you can utilize MATLAB's [`datacursormode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) object, which does not block zooming/panning of your figure window.

A small example (assumes R2014b or newer):

```
h.myfig = figure;
h.myax = axes;

plot(h.myax, 1:10);

% Initialize data cursor object
cursorobj = datacursormode(h.myfig);
cursorobj.SnapToDataVertex = 'on'; % Snap to our plotted data, on by default

while ~waitforbuttonpress 
    % waitforbuttonpress returns 0 with click, 1 with key press
    % Does not trigger on ctrl, shift, alt, caps lock, num lock, or scroll lock
    cursorobj.Enable = 'on'; % Turn on the data cursor, hold alt to select multiple points
end
cursorobj.Enable = 'off';

mypoints = getCursorInfo(cursorobj);
```

Note that you may need to click inside the figure window to trigger the data cursor.

Here I use [`waitforbuttonpress`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitforbuttonpress.html) to control our `while` loop. As commented, `waitforbuttonpress` returns `0` for a mouse button click and `1` for a key press, but is not triggered by the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Caps</kbd>, <kbd>Num</kbd>, or <kbd>ScrLk</kbd> keys. You can select multiple points by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you click.

Once you're done selecting points, hit any key that triggers `waitforbuttonpress` and your data points are output by calling `getCursorInfo`, which returns a data structure containing information on your points. This data structure contains 2 or 3 fields, depending on what is plotted. The structure will always contain `Target`, which is the handle of the graphics object containing the data point, and `Position`, which is an array specifying the x, y, (and z) coordinates of the cursor. If you have plotted a `line` or `lineseries` object you will also have `DataIndex`, which is a scalar index into the data arrays that correspond to the nearest data point.

Comment: This is the more elegant solution.  I couldn't figure out how exactly to do it. +1.

Comment: @excaza I tried using this and for me it doesn't actually work. When I click on the zoom symbol an then click on some point in the image it automatically switches to the cursor without zooming in. Am I doing something wrong? BTW: I'm using R2016a on a Mac if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Still another method could be to use the function enableDefaultInteractivity() which enables using the mouse wheel to zoom in and out:

```
enableDefaultInteractivity(gca);
[x, y, b] = ginput();
```

It works fine with my version of Matlab (9.9.0.1524771 (R2020b) Update 2, on Linux Fedora).